# F# Discriminated Unions access values

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I have a application which runs as a server, dose some calculations and returns a value. I have created a discriminated union type of `MessageType` so I can have different types of messages passed between applications.

The `MessageType` is made up of an `ExchangeMessage` of type `ExchangeFrame`. The question I have is how to access the values of `ExchangeFrame` from the `MessageType`.

The code might explain it better

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type ExchangeFrame = 
    { 
    FrameType: FrameType
    Amount: double;
    ConvertTo: Currency
    ConvertFrom: Currency 
    }

type MessageType = ExchangeMessage of ExchangeFrame

let server () = 
    use context = new Context()

    // socket to talk to clients
    use responder = context |> Context.rep
    "tcp://*:5555" |> Socket.bind responder

    Console.WriteLine("Server Running")

    while true do
        // wait for next request from client
        let messageReceived = responder |> Socket.recv |> decode |> deserializeJson<MessageType> 

        //Do Calculations
        let total = doCalculations //MessageReceived.ExchangeMessage.Amount 3.0 

        // send reply back to client
        let message = encode <| total
        message |> Socket.send responder

server ()
```

Comment: Dont you just want `match somevar with |ExchangeMessage(frame) -> .. //do something with frame`

Comment: Thanks John, but I am still a little confused on how I can access each value in my exchangeframe. can you elaborate a little please

Comment: Then you can just do `frame.Amount` or whatever

Comment: Comment on naming: for single case DUs, it's standard to have the case be named after the type like this `type MessageType = MessageType of ExchangeFrame` or    
`type ExchangeMessage = ExchangeMessage of ExchangeFrame`

Comment: It's not clear to me why the extra `MessageType` wrapper is needed at all. Why not use the `ExchangeFrame` directly?

Answer (score 1):

As the design stands, you can access the exchange frame by (1) pattern matching to extract the frame from the MessageType, and then (2) dotting into the frame to extract a field, like this:

```
let msgType = // creation
let (ExchangeMessage frame) = msgType
let amount = frame.Amount
```

But see my comments to the question.